# Using grep for an unknown pattern with multiple words in row

Tags: regex, bash, grep

**Description:**

My code asks for an argument that could have multiple words. I have a file with multiple lines. I need to search this file for this given argument as a fixed string pattern; the words must be in the order given in the argument, and they must occur entirely within a line in the file. I also need to count the number of instances the argument, as a whole and complete string, is found in the file.

I cannot possibly know the argument in advance so I can't hard code the individual words like `grep -i 'first\|second\|third' /file/name` nor can I use pipes like `grep -i first /file/name | grep -i second | grep -i third`. I won't know how many words are in the argument either, it could be any number of words from 1 to 5.

I've tried `fgrep "$@" /file/name`, `fgrep -f`, `grep -F`, and `grep -w` but my output says

```
grep: second: No such file or directory
grep: third: No such file or directory
```

**Sample file and code:**

My file goes something like

```
Apple → Amy Lee Brown
Orange → Amy Lee Sandborn
Pinapple → Amy Vasluk
Watermelon → Amy
Zuchinni → Lee
```

Someone is asked to enter a name, and the code returns the fruit.

My code goes like this

```
if [ $(grep -ic "$@" $temp/log) -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "$(grep -ic "$@" $temp/log) entries found, please be more specific."
    exit
elif [ $(grep -ic "$@" $temp/log) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "None found, please check name and try again."
    exit
fi

echo $(cat $temp/log | grep -i "$@" | awk '{print $1}')
```

**Objectives:**

- I need to check for count so if the person enters `Amy Lee`, the output should say there are 2 entries, and then ask the person to be more specific.
- I also need `Amy Lee` to **not** match with `Lee`, which is another issue I've run into and can't fix.
- If the person enters `Amy`, I need the output to return 1 entry and to return `Watermelon`, but I can't get it to recognise the input `Amy` as complete and whole, so the code currently outputs 4 entries and asks the user to be more specific - but I can't be more specific, because "Amy" exists in that file and has a fruit assignment.
- Now as I type this sample I realise I may possibly have a dilemma, because if I need my code to match "Amy" exactly, then the same would be done for "Amy Lee" and the code would simply return a 0 count and not even ask the person to be more specific.

Ugh!

Any help or light shed on this would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Working solution provided by Walter A:

```
count=$(grep -ic "$*" $temp/log)
case $count in
    0) echo "No entries found, please check input and try again.";;
    1) echo $(cat $temp/log | grep -i "$*" | awk '{print $1}');;
    *) echo -e "Multiple entries found, please be more specific.\nEnd your search term with '$' for an exact match.";;
esac
exit
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Sorry about that. Added to the question!

Comment: I get confused by your first code `'first\|second\|third'`. This suggests you want to find lines with either of the arguments, Your examples show, that a call to your mygrep.sh with `mygrep.sh first second third` should result in a search to "first second third".

Comment: @WalterA No, that was an example of what I can't use. I brought it up because as I was searching for solutions, that was the one answer that kept coming up, and I wanted to state that that is not what I was looking for because it's not what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$*` not `$@`:

```
num=$(grep -c "$*" /file/name)
case $num in
   0) echo "Not found";;
   1) grep "$*" /file/name
      echo "now use something like cut on the result"
      ;;
   *) echo "Too much";;
esac
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! This works flawlessly. Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't suppose you could also include a way to make it search for an exact match please? When searching for "Amy" it gives the "Too much" output, but to get it to match the existing "Amy" in the file would be brilliant. I still have no idea how to get that to happen. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance, and thanks again for the code!

Edit: Oh darnit. Just realised that if an exact match does happen, then I would run into trouble when searching for half a full name. Searching "Amy Lee" would fail with 0 results if using an exact match search. I'm at my wit's end with this one!

Comment: When you want to find Amy at the end of the line, you can call your script with an `$` (end of line character): `myscript.sh Amy$`.

Comment: When you format your data file with something like `Watermelon:Amy` you can use `cut -d: -f1` for finding the fruit and `myscript.sh :Amy$` for an exact match.

Comment: The end of line character search is brilliant! I'll just print an instruction to let the user know to use it when searching. I'm probably not able to use cut, though, as the actual file has varying numbers of words where the fruit names go and I have to print the whole string up to the → delimiter (which I'm still trying to figure out how to do). Thanks so much for your help here!

Comment: Is the → one character (that you can use with cut -c) or two characters (like `-` and `>`? In the last case use `sed 's/->.*//'`.

Comment: You are beautiful. `sed 's/→.*//'` works flawlessly! You've solved all my problems! Thank you so much!